# Php Outer Quotes Not Working

Tags: php

This is so strange, i tried a bunch of combinations for the quotes but with no positive results, i just want to put the children_of_row variable to be inside a string, but it's not working as i expect, this is strange but since i know that it is me that is wrong and not php i want you guys to tell me where is my "mistake" ? 
 (anything that helps me understand nesting php strings is appreciated).

$children_of_array is an array, $children_of_row["qu‌​estion_name"] is a string when i use php's gettype function, i push the value into $children_of_array, and then inside a php echo statement i implode the array (can i run php functions inside the echo statement ?), but even if i don't the results are the same, when outputted into javascript the type is not string anymore.

```
array_push($children_of_array,'".$children_of_row["question_name"]."');
```

Comment: it is when i use php's gettype but not when i output it to a javascript array with an echo statement. what is this caused by ?

Comment: `'"".$children_of_row["question_name"].""'` ?

Comment: nope, it's $children_of_row btw, not $children_of_array

Comment: value of `$children_of_ro‌​w["question_name"]` already string. what else ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the string of `$children_of_row["question_name"]`, you just need to put that:

```
array_push($children_of_array, $children_of_row["question_name"]);
```

As long as the variable is already a string, or a value that is allowed in an array (including arrays), it'll work.

Comment: no i want to put $children_of_row inside a string, i am getting the value from sql and want to change it to a string.

Comment: What do you mean "inside a string"? What is happening when you run the code, and what do you *want* to happen?